# Making column with minimum time-series value python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with structure:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                 'age':[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2],
                 'value':[2.2,2.1,2.3,3.2,3.1,3.3,4.3,4.4,4.2]})
```

I would like to have a column *minimum* where the *value* corresponding to the minimum *age* for every *id* is reported like:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                 'age':[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2],
                 'value':[2.0,2.1,2.2,3.0,3.1,3.2,4.0,4.1,4.2], 
                 'minimum':[2.2,2.2,2.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,4.3,4.3,4.3]})
```

unfortunately, I am at loss as to how to do this simple task as I don't think the R-way (splitting over *id*, taking the minimum and then using do.call) carries over to python as much. I am sure it is trivial, but I can't seem to get around this in python.

Thank you to whomever could help on this.

Edit: in R, I would do something like:

```
df_list<-split(df,as.factor(df$id))

df_list1<-sapply(df_list,function(df){
            df$min=df$value[which(df$age==min(df$age)]
}) 

df1=do.call("rbind.data.frame",df_list1)
```

Comment: `df.groupby('id')['age'].transform('min')`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but not exactly. This returns the minimum *age*, whereas I am looking for the *value* corresponding to the minimum age. I edited my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmin` to find the location of minimum values, then use `loc` access:

```
df['minimum'] = df.loc[df.groupby('id').age.transform('idxmin'), 'value'].values
```

Or you can use `sort_values` with `drop_duplicates`, then `map`:

```
df['minimum'] = df['id'].map(df.sort_values('age')
                               .drop_duplicates('id')
                               .set_index('id')['value']
                            )
```

Output:

```
   id  age  value  minimum
0   1    0    2.2      2.2
1   1    1    2.1      2.2
2   1    2    2.3      2.2
3   2    0    3.2      3.2
4   2    1    3.1      3.2
5   2    2    3.3      3.2
6   3    0    4.3      4.3
7   3    1    4.4      4.3
8   3    2    4.2      4.3
```